# Why "operand = (operand*10) + (expression[i] - '0');"

Tags: c++, stack, parentheses

Why is the following code doing `operand * 10`?  Why doesn't it just do `operand = (expression[i] - '0');` rather than `operand = (operand*10) + (expression[i] - '0');`

```
else if(IsNumericDigit(expression[i]))    
{
    int operand = 0; 
    while(i<expression.length() && IsNumericDigit(expression[i])) 
    {
        operand = (operand*10) + (expression[i] - '0'); 
        // why is he doing operand *10? 
        // example : if have a string 2 3 * 3 4 +. 
        // It is pushing 23 on stack rather than 2 and 3                
        i++;
    }
    i--;

    S.push(operand);
}
```

Comment: If he do operand = (expression[i]-'0') and expression is "123" then after while loop operand will be 3 not 123.

Comment: Please edit the question body to contain the actual question. The title should just be a short summary of the problem, and the comment should be outside the code as the main question. Please also add some context, and elaborate a little bit on what you're unsure of. But first please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Of course the idea is to process larger numbers like 42. Well, it should exit the while loop because ' ' is not a numeric digit. Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: question is to evaluate a given postfix expression   example: 2 3 * 4 + =10 alright?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz understood my ques?

Comment: @AashishKalia I didn't even try to understand the question, what I meant is that you should format (or [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)) your code so that other people (including yourself) can read it easily. Someone just did it for you, look at your question again. You see the difference?

Comment: If `2 3 *` is causing 23 to be pushed on the stack (rather than 2 and 3), the problem is elsewhere.  The code is as it is, so that `12 3 *` will push 12 and 3 on the stack.

Comment: Does IsNumericDigit handle whitespace correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Because it was told to. Consider you have 2 3 4 5 i your expression array. Then your code `operand = (operand*10) + (expression[i] - '0');` will do following:

```
operand = (0*10) + (2-0)
operand = (2*10) + (3-0)
operand = (23*10) + (4-0)
operand = (234*10) + (5-0)
```

So at the end your operand will contain number 2345. It is like if you write number down on the paper. First you write down 2, then you write 3 after it. Now you have 23 which is same as 20 + 3. Hence multiplying by 10.

Comment: Hello Aashish did it help you? If so please consider marking it as answer. It will not only reward author of the solution, but will help others. Not to mention that when someone is looking on unsolved questions, yours is still popping up and wasting time of others. This is not fair to those who are trying to solve your problem.